# Emacs: how to get Russian to display as single width?

Tags: fonts, emacs, locale, chinese-locale, widechar

Please tell me how to get Russian to display as single width,

```
$ cat file
ABCDкомм中文1234

$ cat .emacs
(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "-sony-fixed-medium-r-normal--16-120-100-100-c-80-iso8859-1")))
```

without disturbing anything else which looks perfect currently for me.

My .emacs causes Russian to appear in

```
xft:-WenQ-文泉驛點陣正黑-normal-normal-normal-*-16-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1
```

instead of the default

```
xft:-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
```

But I want to keep my .emacs line, as it makes everything else look good for me.
Same problem for Greek.
Emacs 25.2.2.

P.S., my LC_CTYPE=zh_TW.UTF-8, and I don't want to change it either.

OK... reading (info "(emacs) Modifying Fontsets") ... will try...

Answer (score 2):

Based on (info "(emacs) Modifying Fontsets"), one finds adding

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'cyrillic "DejaVu Sans Mono")
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'greek "DejaVu Sans Mono")
```

Works!